# App Declining in app updates through app center

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I set up Microsoft update according to the app centre documentation however I am getting the following dialogue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin

I am using android 9.1 i used the normal download function 
Steps to reproduce

1 I had to install new version on Phone so downloaded via email

2 Sent a new version to app centre for testing the below

3 Presented with that dialogue when I started the app

I places this in my OnCreate in MainActivty.cs

```
AppCenter.Start("{secret key}", typeof(Distribute));
```

And the following in my App.Xaml

```
AppCenter.Start("android=secret-key;",
          typeof(Distribute), typeof(Distribute));
```

I also placed this in OnStart

```
Distribute.SetEnabledAsync(true);
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting the below dialogue

[image: ?]

My App is also in release mode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not have two calls to `Start` in different places and two Distribute types passed.

- If you have a `Xamarin.Forms` app, call to `Start` should happen
  inside `App.xaml.cs`.
- If you have a `Xamarin.Android` app, call to `Start` should happen
  inside `MainActivity.cs`.

Not the both!

`typeof(Distribute)` should be passed only once.
Please refer to [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#42-add-the-start-method) of documentation.

Also, calling `setEnabled` is unnecessary.